# TCL: what is the difference between format , binary format , scan and binary scan commands?

Tags: tcl

Can anyone explain me the differences between `scan` and `binary scan` .

`format` and `binary format` .

I am getting confusion with the binary commands .

Answer (score 2):

To understand the difference between command sets manipulating binary and string data you have to understand the distinction between these two kinds of data.

In Tcl, as in many (most?) high-level languages, strings are rather abstract — that is, they are described in pretty high-level terms.  Particularly in Tcl, strings are defined to have the following properties:

- They contain characters from the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org) repertoire.
- The Tcl runtime provides the set of standard commands to operate on strings — such as indexing, searching, appending to, extracting a substring etc.

Note that many things are left out from this definition:

- The encoding in which these Unicode characters are stored.
- How exactly they are stored (`NUL`-terminated arrays? linked lists of `unsigned long`s? something else?).

(To put it into a more interesting perspective, Tcl is able to transparently change the underlying representations of strings it manages — between `UTF-8` and `UTF-16` encoded sequences.  But here we're talking about [the reference Tcl implementation](http://core.tcl.tk), and other implementations (such as [Jacl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/jacl) for instance) are free to do something else completely.)

The same approach is used to manipulate all the other kinds of data in the Tcl interpreter.  Say, integer numbers are stored using native platform "integers" (roughly "as in C") but they are transparently upgraded into arbitrary sized integers if an arithmetic operation is about to overflow the platform-sized result.

So long as you don't leave the comfortable world of the Tcl interpreter, this is all you should know about the data types it manages.  But now there's the outside world.  In it, abstract concepts which are Tcl strings do not exist.  Say, if you need to communicate to some other program over a network socket or by means of using a file or whatever other kind of media, you *have to* get down to the level of exact layouts of raw bytes which are described by ["wire protocols"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_protocol) and [file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format) or whatever applies to your case.  This is where "binaries" come into play: they allow you to precisely specify how the data is laid out so that it's ready to be transferred to the outside world or be consumed from it — `binary format` makes these "binaries" and `binary scan` reads them.

Note that certain Tcl commands for working with the outside world are "smart by default" — for instance, the `open` command which opens files by default assumes they are textual and are encoded in the default system encoding (which is deduced, broadly speaking, from the environment).  You can then use the `chan configure` (of `fconfigure` — in older versions of Tcl) command to either change this encoding or completely inhibit conversions by specifying the channel is in "binary mode".  The same applies to [EOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) conversions.

Note also that there are specialized packages for Tcl that effectively hide the complexities of working with a particular wire/file format.  To present one example, the [tdom](http://wiki.tcl.tk/tdom) package works with `XML`; when you manipulate `XML` using this package, you're not concerned with how exactly `XML` must be represented when, say, saved to a file — you just work with tdom's objects, native Tcl strings etc.

Comment: So .. from your explanation , binary scan reads the binary data . But in my example i passed the ascii character "[binary scan abcdefg s3s first second]"

Comment: @user3103694, OK that's *another question* completely. In Tcl, commands interpret the values they're passed by themselves. The `binary scan` command will ask the Tcl interpreter to make a byte array out of its first argument (using a call to [`Tcl_GetByteArrayFromObj`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/ByteArrObj.htm) and then use *that representation* to work on.  What would it do with a Tcl string value?  Most probably, it will interpret it as an array of `UTF-8` encoded characters.

Comment: @user3103694. after that, `binary scan` will pick these bytes by pairs, according to the `s3s` specification.

Comment: Point of reference: `binary scan` uses the _low_ byte of each Unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are pretty good and contain examples:

- scan: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/scan.htm
- format: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm
- binary scan: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/binary.htm#M42
- binary format: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/binary.htm#M16

Maybe you could ask a more specific question?

Comment: [binary scan] parses fields from a binary string, returning the number of conversions performed.

"binary scan abcdefg s3s first second"

The command description is saying that the input should be binary string .. but in the example I passes characters .. I am getting confused with these terms .

Answer (score 0):

The `format` command assembles strings of ***characters***, the `binary format` command assembles strings of ***bytes***. The `scan` and `binary scan` commands do the reverse, extracting formation from character strings and byte strings respectively.

Note that Tcl happens to map byte strings neatly onto character strings where the characters are in the range `\u0000`–`\u00FF`, and there are other operations for getting information into and out of binary strings that are sometimes relevant. Most notably, `encoding convertto` and `encoding convertfrom`: `encoding convertto` formats a string as a sequence of bytes that represent that string *in a given encoding* (an operation which can lose information) and `encoding converfrom` goes in the opposite direction.

---

So what encoding are Tcl's strings *really* in? Well, none really. Or many. The logical level works with character sequences exclusively, and the implementation will actually move things back and forth (mostly between a variant of UTF-8 and UCS-2, though with optimisations for handling byte strings via arrays of `unsigned char`) as necessary. While this is not always perfectly efficient, most code never notices what's going on due to the type-caching used.

If you have Tcl 8.6, you can *peek* behind the covers to observe the types with an unsupported command:

```
# Output is human-readable; experiment to see what it says for you
puts [tcl::unsupported::representation $MyString]
```

Don't use this to base functional decisions on; Tcl is *very* happy to mutate types out from under your feet. But it can help when finding out why your code is unexpectedly slow. (Note also that types attach to values, and not to variables.)